# Tkinter Not Opening Window

Tags: function, user-interface, button, tkinter, window

I am creating a program that allows a user to make a custom dice, but when I open a GUI window with a button that calls the backend dice roll logic, it breaks. In other words, the window doesn't open, and the code just runs in the terminal. It doesn't happen when the button is clicked like I want it to, instead when I run the code, it doesn't open any GUI window and the code executes in the terminal. The code works without the GUI, and if i take out the dice button callback, the GUI works but together it doesn't.

Any help is appreciated!

```py
import random
import tkinter as tk


def dice_roll():
      dice = []
      x = 0

# used to check if the input is a whole number, if it isn't, you get a message
while True:
    while x == 0:
        try:
            SIDE_AMT = int(input("How many sides would you like? (min is 2, max is infinite): "))    # amt is amount
            x = 1
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry it has to be a whole number.")

    if SIDE_AMT > 1:
        for side in range(SIDE_AMT):
            print(f"What would you like side {side + 1} to be?:")
            dice.append(str(input()))
        break
    else:
        print("You can't have a dice with one side!")
        x = 0

# roll function
def roll():
    dice_side = random.choice(dice)
    print(f"I choose {dice_side}!")

roll_num = 0
while True:
    if roll_num == 0:
        spin_it = str(input("Type 'roll' if you would like to roll the dice: "))
        if spin_it == "roll":
            roll()
        else:
            print("Sorry, you have to type roll correctly.")
        roll_num += 1

    elif roll_num == 1:
        while True:
            spin_it = str(input("Type 'roll' if you would like to roll the dice again!: "))
            if spin_it == "roll":
                roll()
            else:
                print("Sorry, you have to type roll correctly.")


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      gui = tk.Tk()
      gui.title("Dice Roll")
      gui.geometry("1912x1090")
      gui.configure(bg='#a2a2a1', borderwidth=5,                   
                    relief="raised")

      # title
      title = tk.Label(gui, text='Unique Dice', font=("Times             
      New Roman", 52))
      title.configure(bg='#a2a2a1', fg='#195190', 
      borderwidth=3, relief='raised')

      # make a dice?
      dice = tk.Button(gui,
                       text="Yes!",
                       fg="red",
                       command=dice_roll())

      no_dice = tk.Button(gui,
                          text="No",
                          fg="red",
                          command=quit)

      # frame = tk.Frame(gui, height=200, width=200)
      # frame['borderwidth'] = 10
      # frame['relief'] = 'sunken'
      # frame.pack()

      dice.pack()
      no_dice.pack()
      title.pack()
      gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: first of at `if __name__ == '__main__':` you should put just the main functions also that part of the code will never get executed as there is a while loop thats blocking it

Comment: also what exactly do you want to get displayed?

Comment: it wont open any GUI because the script runs in a loop

Answer (score 0):

you may want to do something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import choice


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x600')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.config(bg='light blue')

dice_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
rolled_nums = []


def roll():
    if len(rolled_nums):
        rolled_nums[0].pack_forget()
        rolled_nums.pop(0)
    chosen_number = choice(dice_numbers)
    text = tk.Label(root, text=f'{chosen_number}',
                                font='arial 500 bold', bg='light blue')
    text.pack()
    rolled_nums.append(text)


button = tk.Button(root, text='Roll Dice!', font='arial 20 bold', relief='raised', width='300',
                   bg='dark red', fg='black', command=lambda: roll())
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

fell free to adjust this code and if you have questions -> ask

Comment: Oops, when i typed the code there I meant everything except for the stuff under name == main to be in the dice roll function

Comment: Also why did you use lambda for the command on the button?

Comment: @KylenWilliams tbh idk I should learn about it but you can try doing without  and see what happens